# Bower install multiple version of lodash in angularjs 1.4.9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash, bower

I uses `lodash version 4.x` in my project and it has to import a library Book-Activity uses `lodash version 2.x` and another library that requires `lodash version 2.x`

Is it possible to install and load 2 versions of lodash in my project?
If yes, how i can i do?

Thanks

Comment: More often then not libraries are backwards-compatible. Check if you may have only latest version. And why so ancient angularjs version?

Comment: Cause I am working on old system, and i have to upgrade to new version. But the services and factory was long time ago and right now I can't changes from it.